# Display Custom Payload in Telegram

Tags: node.js, api, dialogflow-es, telegram

I am sending a custom payload to DialogFlow and I want it to be displayed in Telegram. When I send just a text response Telegram can display it but it cannot display a custom payload. This is what I get in the fulfillment response in DialogFlow:

```
"fulfillmentMessages": [
    {
      "payload": {
        "messages": [
          {
            "type": "yellow,
            "text": "lorem ipsum"
          }
        ]
      },
      "platform": "PLATFORM_UNSPECIFIED"
    }
  ],
  "outputContexts": []
}
```

I am sending the payload in this manner:

```
const agent = new dfff.WebhookClient({
        request: req,
        response: res
    })
    const demo = async function(agent) {
         //more code
         agent.add(new dfff.Payload(agent.UNSPECIFIED, payload, {sendAsMessage: true, rawPayload: true}));
    }
    let intentMap = new Map();
    intentMap.set('MyIntent', demo);
    agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
```

This is what payload looks like:

```
let payload = {
            "messages": [
                {
                    "type": "text",
                    "text": "Select your favorite food category or send me your location!",
                }
            ]};
```

How can I get it to display inside of Telegram?

Comment: Can you show how `payload` is constructed?

Comment: I have edited it to include what payload looks like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For you to display the custom payload in telegram, you should follow the payload structure as mentioned in [Dialogflow Telegram integration](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/integrations/telegram#custom_payload_responses).

> ```
> {
>   "telegram": {
>     "text": "You can read about *telegram docs* [here](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/integrations/telegram).",
>     "parse_mode": "Markdown"
>   }
> }
> ```

`parse_mode` can be either Markdown, MarkdownV2 or HTML style. You can check [telegram formatting options](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#formatting-options) for more details on how to format messages.

Also on your code change the agent to `agent.TELEGRAM`.

```
agent.add(new dfff.Payload(agent.TELEGRAM, payload, {sendAsMessage: true, rawPayload: true}));
```

The bot's reply using the custom payload looks like this:
[image]